# Intersection of nested compact subspaces in non-Hausdorff space

Tags: general-topology, compactness

Why is it that if a space is not Hausdorff and you take the intersection of nested compact subspaces the intersection could be empty? Could you give me an example?

Answer (score 3):

Take $X$ to be any set with the trivial topology (only the empty set and $X$ are open). Every subset of $X$ is compact.
Now take any chain of subsets whose intersection is empty.

For example, $\mathbb N$ with the trivial topology and intersect $A_k = \{n\in\mathbb N\mid n>k\}$.

---

This idea transfer to any space that has the property that every subspace is compact (this is known as a Noetherian space). For example co-finite topologies have this property.

Comment: If the space is non-Hausdorff, what can we say about the nested intersection of connected subsets? Is the intersection connected?

Comment: @upaudel: I don't know. You should ask this as a new question perhaps.