# Counter example for Cantor's intersection theorem

Tags: analysis

Could anyone point out which line of the following reasoning is incorrect?

Let $\mathbb R$ be equipped with the indiscrete topology, $\{\emptyset,  \mathbb R\}$.

1. Then, every subset of $\mathbb R$ is compact.
2. The sequence of sets $\{(n, \infty)\mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is decreasing and all compact.
3. According to Cantor's intersection, the intersection of the sequence of sets should be non-empty.

However, 3. is obviously false. Is Cantor's intersection theorem only applied to metric space? Is there any generalized version to only get the non-empty intersection result?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/247645/intersection-of-nested-compact-subspaces-in-non-hausdorff-space

Answer (score 2):

The proof uses the fact that the complement of a compact set is open, which as we see is not true in every topological space. It's true in any Hausdorff space.